# Problem with adding query function with another function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

newbie here!
I was testing and practicing the query function, when I came across this function on a website

`={QUERY($A$11:$B$61,"select A, sum(B) group by A order by sum(B) desc label sum(B) 'Total Positions'",1);{"TOTAL",SUM($B$11:$B$61)}}`

The idea here is to put a total row after the created query.

When I tried to apply this function on my sheets, the query function was stuck on the data tab, and did not move into the query clauses.

I know am doing something wrong, I just don't know what it is.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to continue writing after the comma?

Comment: This happens when dealing with arrays. The highlighting doesn't line up with the current argument you have selected. It's annoying, but fret not it's perfectly fine. It will work just fine, it just won't show which argument you're typing out.

Comment: @Daniele Yes, I tried and it didn't work, even when I copy and paste the function provided in the website I saw the function on .. it doesn't work

Comment: @DavidTan 
Thanks mate, I thought it was a visual glitch, I was told on a discord server that it was a visual glitch, tho I'm afraid its not. Because when I copy and pasted the function provided in a website, it also didn't work.

Comment: Could you post a link to your file?